# DATE_ADD yields Unrecognized Keyword error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In `phpMyAdmin` trying to update a `date` field in a table with this syntax:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET 'date' = DATE_ADD('date', INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

However, I immediately get the following errors:

> Unrecognized Keyword. (near INTERVAL)
>  Unexpected Token. (near
>   7)
>  Unrecognized Keyword. (near DAY)
>  Unexpected Token (near
>   ))

I don't understand why. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this? Thank you!

**EDIT**
I resolved my issue by using this line:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET 'date' = ADDDATE('date', 7)
```

However, I'm still curious why the original query doesn't work.

Comment: Does it let you run the query regardless of the displayed errors? What phpMyAdmin version do you have? There were a few problems with the parser a few minor versions ago, but they should all be fixed in the current release.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take back-ticks `` instead of single-quotes `'`:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Recommendation: You should not name a column `date` since that's a reserved word in MySQL. Take `startdate`, `enddate`, `orderdate`, ...

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in phpmyadmin versions below 4.5.5 where the INTERVAL keyword in not recognised.

Changelog: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.5.5/

I had the same issue and updating the version showed my query as valid and running it worked as expected.